# Converting string column to datetime column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, date, datetime

I have an attribute column that has a string datetime and I want to convert that to a date column. I first attempted to simply add the `time` column in an expression, and I only got the `year/month/date`, but I wanted the time as well. So I first converted it the string to a new column with `format_date()`, to clean up the format, and then I went ahead and used `to_datetime()` to convert the string into the date column. It shows up fine in the Expression dialogue but then doesn't add the `hour/minute/seconds`.

What am I overlooking?

Using
QGIS version
3.16.1-Hannover
on Windows

[image]

Comment: Which one is your source column? What file format is it and which datatype did you choose?

Comment: It was because I converted a CSV to a shapefile, so problem solved. Shapefiles apparently don't store date and time in same field.

Answer (score 6):

You probably use shapefile format. Otherwise it should have worked.

According to the [documentation](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012836) shapefile format doesn't store date and time in the same field. You need to add date and time to seperate columns or use other format like GeoPackage.

Comment: You know that was it, I didn't know that about shapefiles. I converted from a CSV to a shapefile and it went all wonky. I'm using a geopackage now and it works perfectly.

Comment: I have just learned that after your question. :) I have not used date and  time in shapefile so far.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with column "IGNITIONDA" with values like "1930/11/01 00:00:00.000".

I converted this to only date column (but you can also add the time) in two steps. first you need to convert the format  from string to either only date or only time or with combination with command:

*format_date("IGNITIONDA" , 'yyyyMMdd')*

Running this will create a column (here I named "ig_date") with only string having value "19301101". Now convert this string to the date with command to new column with date type:

*to_date("ig_date",'yyyyMMdd')*

Running the above commands will give the column with value type

*<date: 1930-11-01>*